# iOS - Creating a custom tab bar navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

[image]

- How can I go about creating a top navigation tab bar (That is the utmost top of the page - no title on top) in iOS like the
  one in the Reddit app? On tap, pages simply slide left or right along
  with the indicator under the page label (No back arrows as presented by a regular nav controller).
- I've thoroughly searched Google for any tutorials resembling this
  with no success.

Comment: Add a UIPageViewController and UISegmentControl to your viewController. In SegmentControl did tap load specific VC associated with segment in UIPageViewControl you can do that by setting currently selected viewController of UIPageViewControl

Comment: If it's ok to be a library, I would suggest to check https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Comment: @Babiker how u created above view which is marked in red i need to create same like Reddit

Comment: @DilipTiwari I think I just used a 3rd party library.

Comment: could u share that plz @Babiker i wan same feature and also with left bar item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are good third-party controls offering this functionality.

Try one of these:

**Objective-C**

- **https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers**
- https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNSegmentedControl
- https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl

My personal recommendation is [**first**](https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers). It allows you to implement neat transmission between view controllers with gestures.

**Swift**

- https://github.com/Yalantis/Segmentio

Comment: Thanks, all of those are objective c, I'm looking for a swift implementation.

Comment: Added one in Swift. Other than that they bridge fairly well.

Answer (score 1):

Use **ScrollableSegmentedControl**

https://github.com/GocePetrovski/ScrollableSegmentedControl

Comment: It might be a "not bad" suggestion, but I would suggest to add it as a comment instead of answer.